# Flash CS4 AS3 Event not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

I can't attach a simple event handler to a lousy movie clip. Not a single tutorial worked for me and I followed them carefully. Over an hour wasted for nothing... again! Here's what I did:

*Layer1:* created a symbol(movie clip). Added a rectangle. Draged it onto the layer. Added a name 'obj' in the Properties window. Exported it for ActionScript.

*Layer2:* Open Action Panel and wrote the following:

```
obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, move);

function move(event:MouseEvent):void {
    obj.x = 200;
    obj.y = 200;
}
```

I don't know what I might be overlooking. I tried with the `import flash.events.Event;` at the top. Although it wasn't present in the tutorials I've watched(on youtube).

P.S. Needless to say, I'm just starting with ActionScript 3.0 but I am reading about the basics on adobe.com

Comment: You have to add an instance of that MovieClip to your stage (from the library), or create one by code, and call it `obj` to get that code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. Adding a name for the movie clip symbol is one thing. But when we drag it onto the stage, then we have to click it. And THEN, in the properties tab of the object on the scene, we give it a (class) name. So that ActionScript can see and use it. Right-clicking on the movie clip in the Library tab and selecting Properties is NOT the properties we're looking for.

*Edit:* Thanks, **akmozo**. I just found that out. Took me long enough!

*Edit2:* Just wanted to point out something - when I save a project in Flash CS4 which has an event handler. The handler didn't work. The code itself, that is. I tried the same project in CS3 and it worked fine. So part of the problem was the program itself(Flash CS4).